# Can I obtain method Fields name using Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class like this:

```
public class Whatever {
    public void aMethod(int Param) {
        ExecutionContext executionContext ;
    } 
}
```

is there any way to know that `aMethod` uses a `Field` named `executionContext` ?

Comment: No, Reflection doesn't inspect the method's body.

Comment: This is a method local variable. A field on the other hand is an instance variable (or - if static - a class variable). Method local variables cannot be _reflected_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is about language level introspection, but not that deep.

**You cannot do that with reflection, you can do that by using static analysis tool (AST investigation).**

BTW the `executionContext` is not field, but local variable.